# jQuery Mobile with ASP.NET MVC - UI follows post target following execution of JavascriptResult action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile site for an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 website, and have opted to use jQuery mobile. So far so good, but when I try to reuse one of my views that performs an Ajax post to an action that returns JavaScriptResult, the UI ends up following the post URL rather than just running the JavaScript that is returned.

Since this is a reused action and for the desktop site, all browsers just execute the JavaScript and remain on the page as intended, I can only assume that something in jQuery mobile, causes the additional behaviour which causes the browser to follow the URL.

Can anyone tell me what, and how I might prevent the browser from following the post URL?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "AjaxLoadGif" }))
{

    ... form elements etc

    <input id="btn" class="btn" type="submit" name="" value="Click Me"/>
}
```

The target action looks something like...

```
public JavaScriptResult DoSomething(SomeInfo info)
{

    return JavaScript('showValidationErrorHtml(); return false;');

}
```

The browser ends up at http://site.com/Controller/DoSomething

Answer (score 1):

You have to specifically tell jQuery Mobile to not hi-jack the form submission. You can do that by setting the `data-ajax="false"` attribute on the `<form>` tag:

```
<form data-ajax="false" ...>
    ...
</form>
```

Setting-up the form like this means that you will have to handle the AJAX submission of the form on your own. I'm not familiar with ASP.net MVC 3 but if this is not already being done then here is an example:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#my-form-id', function () {
    //handle form submission, most likely with $.ajax([OPTS]);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give this a try. I thought there'd be something.